# Как реализовать в Edittext ввод символов справа налево

Tags: android, android-edittext

Есть поле  Edittext, в которое пользователь должен ввести ответ, но при этом первый введенный символ должен быть правее, чем второй. Т.е. если пользователь последовательно вводит 123, то в итоге в  Edittext отобразится 321.
Можно ли как-то это реализовать используя 1 поле Edittext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть идеи, насколько я поняла, только в том, чтобы правильно перемещать курсор в поле editText, а именно так, чтобы после первого введенного символа курсор становился перед ним (т.е. слева).

Для этого нужно написать как-то так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements TextWatcher{
 EditText editText;    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);

 @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        editText.setSelection(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {    
    }    
}
```

Ну и в layout для editText соответственно указать свойство gravity right, чтобы все отвечало логике ввода текста справа-налево.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте класс `TextWatcher`. Должно получиться как-то так:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // Здесь опишем логику перестановки символа
                if (before > start)
                   editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: очередность ввода символов не изменилась

Answer (score 1):

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

Поэкспериментируйте со значением этого атрибута

Comment: ничего не меняется, к сожалению