# Android. Писать текст справа налево

Tags: android

Никак не могу решить проблему с "писать текст справа налево". Такая штука мне  нужна для бинарного калькулятора, который нужен на одном из экранов) Видел такой тэг rtl - но он не работает. На английской части стека все говорят про gravity="right", но и это не помогло. Я в шаге от частного самодельного решения этой проблемы) Подскажите, как писать текст в TextEdit справа налево!?

P/S/ EditText обернут в Constarint Layout если это имеет значение.

Comment: какой у вас API? rtl c 17+

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503680/11515

Comment: это как раз то что нужно) Немного доработаю и вообще огонь будет!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте следующее решение:

**xml:**

```
 android:textDirection="rtl"
 android:gravity="right"
```

**Программно:**

```
 textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

или

```
 textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
```

начина с  `API 17+`

Добавлять текст в начало `textView`:

```
textview.setText(number + textView.getText());
```

Comment: я пробовал - оно не работает. Возможно вы знаете, что может блокировать его работу?

Comment: У вас какая минимальная версия андройда стоит в gradle?

Comment: 21 или 23. Я использую Constraint Layout для item.  На основе item создается recyclerView. Если это поможет, я могу привести код того или иного файла.

Comment: хм, а программно пробывали сделать?

Comment: честно говоря не помню( Думаю программно надо попробовать еще раз

Comment: попробуйте, я поправил ответ, добавил программный способ

Comment: получилось, но не совсем то, что хотелось бы. Текст пишется справа налево, но новые значение добавляются справа т. е. 0123 <- 4 <- 5 ... , а хотелось бы .. - > 5 -> 4 -> 3210. Не знаете ли Вы как подобное реализовать? (P/S надеюсь моя анаграмма понятна)

Answer (score 1):

Решил добавить свой итогвый вариант на Kotlin. Этот код позволяет писать текст справа на лево, что каждый следующий символ появляется слева от курсора. Обычный вариант с `textdirection` не дает эффекта "арабского письма"

```
     editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {  }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            // set cursor
            editText.setSelection(start)
        }
    })
```